# Make a post request with okHttp

Tags: java, okhttp

I make a post request using okHttp with the next code:

```
    final MediaType JSON = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, params);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .post(body)
        .build();

    Response response = null;
    response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

The server response with:

```
response
{
  message: {
    user: {
      id: 12,
      name: 'myName'
    },
    message: 'Usuario creado con éxito.',
    code: 200
  }
}
```

But the response that okHttp gives me is:

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://localhost:2222/api/users}
```

There isn´t a way to get what the server sends me with okHttp?

Comment: `response.body().string()`

Comment: With "what the server sends" you mean, the content (message body) of the http response, or the whole (raw) http response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the response is sent in the body you can get it with:

```
response.body().string();
```

You just had to look on the [documentation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Response.html#body--)

¡Salud!

Comment: I try with that but get okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@3f3d2bda

Comment: I think you are using `toString()` and not `string()` that is a method of `ResponseBody`. Refert again to [documentation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html#string--)

Answer (score 1):

What you are getting is the header of response object. you can access the body of response by:

```
response.body().string();
```

full code:

```
final MediaType JSON = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, params);
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .post(body)
        .build();

Response response = null;
response = client.newCall(request).execute();
String responseBody = response.body().string();
```

Comment: I get okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@5da5c9d3 with response.body().string()